# The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception

Tags: c#, emgucv

I use this code in my project.
      `haar = new HaarCascade("face_detect.xml");`
When program run, It gives an exception like "'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception".
Can anybody give me any suggestion why it is?

edit:
I search about this. It says copy some dlls to emgucv. I don't know from where to where need to copy those dlls.

Comment: Well to start with, look at what the inner exception is. I suggest you post the *full* stack trace.

Comment: Most likely you have to add refereences to opencv dlls into your project and let Visual Studio handle everything else. EmguCV is a .NET interface to OpenCV library, which is written in C/C++. So C# objects are just wrappers for unmanaged code in the dlls that ship with OpenCV. I assume Emgu installer install OpenCV libraries somewhere, try finding them. Most likely OpenCV dlls are named something like `opencv_*.dll`, but it depends on version you use.

Answer (score 0):

Add EMGU.cv , EMGU.GPU , EMGU.ML , EMGU.CV.UI , EMGU.CV To Your "References" in "Solution Explorer Window"
Then Add opencv_core290.dll , opencv_gpuimgproc290.dll to your Project In "Solution Explorer Window".
Right Click Project / Add / Add existing item / Goto your Emgucv folder / Goto Bin / *86 / for opencv_core290.dll (if you are running a 2.9 version of Emgu Cv )
Then Check .
You can check this Youtube link too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaAfi1KjaGM